# Aligning Test to the middle of the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to align test to the middle of the navigation bar. My code is below:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Games <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Badge</a>
      <a href="#">Undead Nightmare</a>
      <a href="#">All Games</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Videos</a>
  <a href="#">Newswire</a>
  <a href="#">Social Club</a>
  <a href="#">Downloads</a>
  <a href="#">Warehouse</a>
  <a href="#">Support</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[Nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBAA9.png)
I have tried using `display: inline-block`, I have tried removing `float: left`. All in which i tried below `.navbar a` and a bunch of other ways, but I still can't center it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I generally use things like margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto (which gives centered children nodes)

Comment: I have tried that and nothing has changed

Comment: Take `float:left` out of both `.navbar a` and `.dropdown`, set `.dropdown` to `display:inline-block`, and set `.navbar` to `text-align:center`. You are floating everything left, so making them display `inline`and `inline-block` instead, means you can centre them as you would inline characters.

Comment: Thank you have have done the changes and it has worked,but the drop down part of the menu (Games) is not inline with the rest of the menu

Comment: @KyleLogan you need to adjust your code to correct your submenu in order to align all to center. Consider using ul/li to integrate your dropdown. There are many examples on SO and the web in general.